# Migration of customers and orders from magento to magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, migration

What things to be kept in mind while the migration of customers and orders from an old store in Magento1 to a store in Magento 2.0.

And is there any filter from which I can filter the history of last 4 years and keep and drop the rest??

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this -

Default Magento 2 Migration tool.

" [Guide Link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html) "

[Install tool for a migration](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/blob/master/README.md)

OR

UberTheme Migration tool.

This is easier way to migrate Magento 1.9.X to Magento 2.X.X

" [Guide Link](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-pro-release/) "

[Install tool for a migration](https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration/releases/tag/Version0.1.0)

if still get issue feel free to ask.